# Django Audit Log

Tags: django-auditlog

I want to show logged in user or actor id in my LogEntry Table which is displayed in admin panel. By default is is showing 5 columns Created, Resource, Action,Changes and User. I want to extend user id column in this table that is i want to include user id field to be displayed in that LogEntry table registered in admin panel

i tried AUDITLOG_INCLUDE_TRACKING_MODELS but its giving me list index out of range error when i am putting app_name and model_name.

Thanks in advance[LogEntry table listing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvPEr.png)